# Prove that a series is not uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis

How can i show that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(x+n)^{3/2}}$$ is not uniformly convergent on $[1,\infty)$

I know that for given $\epsilon > 0$, we need to construct a sequence $x_n$ such that $|\frac{x^{2n}}{(x+n)^{3/2}}| > \epsilon$. The thing is I was not able to come up with such a sequence.

Comment: Do you mean "convergent" rather than "continuous"?  I recommend using the ratio test to check for convergence.

Comment: yes... convergent. Sorry!

Comment: No problem.  Did you try the ratio test?

Comment: Yes. I just tried it, but couldn't reach the conclusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not even convergent when $x>1$.  Some ways to see this:

- Ratio test:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^2\left(\frac{x+n}{x+n+1}\right)^{3/2}=x^2.$$
- Root test: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x+n)^{3/(2n)}}=x^2.$$
- Divergence test:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(x+n)^{3/2}}$$ can be calculated with two applications of l'Hôpital's rule if $x>1$.

Comment: That's wonderful. Now I got it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint : given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, how does the function $\frac{x^{2n}}{(x+n)^{3/2}}$ behave when $x$ goes to $+\infty$ ?

You should be able to complete the proof after having answered that question.

Comment: indeed, it approaches infinite. So showing this would be sufficient as a proof?

Comment: with your idea of proof, if it approaches infinity, then a fortiori there is a $x_n$ such that it is greater than $\epsilon$ (as noted by Jonas, it diverges rather crudely).